# What does "snookums" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

A friend is saved snookums name contact list Can anyone explain better when it could be used and.  I've never heard it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: OP originally had "snukums".

---

I believe it is a [pet name](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/pet-name) (nickname for loved one).

> [snookums](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/snookums)
>   noun
>   sweetheart; a term of endearment
>   Usage Note
>   informal

It's a term of endearment you might use for a pet or a loved one.

Similar names include

- Pumpkin
- Honey bear
- Boo/Boo-boo
- Cuddly-wuddly
- Cutie pie

You can find a list of similar names [here](https://pairedlife.com/misc/cute-nicknames).

Comment: Snookums can also be used when making fun of someone for complaining about a hurt that isn't very bad in the grand scheme of things. You say, "Oh, snookums!" and roll your eyes.

Comment: I think she'e loving me may be